# Проблема поиска вхождения строки в файле

Tags: python, строки

Помогите реализовать идею с поиском строки в файле. Мне нужна только подсказка, ибо не могу придумать эффективный алгоритм поиска(

На вход подается строка NNNNNNATRR, где вместо N - любая буква из набора A, T, G, C; R - A или G.
мне нужно найти все вхождения данной строки в файле. Нужно реализовать на python.

Comment: это называется "регулярные выражения".

Answer (score 1):

Для поиска всех вхождений заданной строки в файле можно использовать методы из стандартной библиотеки Python. Один из эффективных способов - это использовать модуль re для работы с регулярными выражениями. Вам также понадобится модуль os для работы с файловой системой. Вот пример кода:

```
import re
import os

def find_occurrences_in_file(file_path, search_string):
    occurrences = []
    pattern = search_string.replace('N', '[ATGC]').replace('R', '[AG]')
    regex = re.compile(pattern)

    with open(file_path, 'r') as file:
        for line_number, line in enumerate(file, start=1):
            matches = regex.finditer(line)
            for match in matches:
                occurrences.append((line_number, match.start(), match.group()))

    return occurrences

# Пример использования:
file_path = 'путь_к_файлу.txt'
search_string = 'NNNNNNATRR'
result = find_occurrences_in_file(file_path, search_string)

for line_number, position, match in result:
    print(f"Вхождение найдено в строке {line_number}, позиция {position}: {match}")
```

В этом коде я сначала преобразую искомую строку `search_string` в регулярное выражение, заменяя `N` на `[ATGC]` и `R` на `[AG]`. Затем читаею файл построчно и использую `finditer` для поиска всех вхождений регулярного выражения в каждой строке. Для каждого вхождения сохраняю номер строки, позицию и найденную подстроку. В результате получаю список всех вхождений.